# angularjs1 collapse same pannel with different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, css

hey guys I'm trying to create a collapsible panel: so should have panel header and panel body to show the content. The behavior on click is when a button is pressed the content will collapse down and if you click the same button the content will close up. If you click the second button will collapse the content for the second button and the first button collapse is closed. Basically should work like a collapsible panel (bootstrap) but developed only with angular. I had done this so far but I'm beginner with angular so if you can help me ...

**[fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/mq74pqft/3/)**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Test" class="container">
  <div class="custom">
    <button ng-click="show = 1" class="btn">collapse 1</button>
    <button ng-click="show = 2" class="btn">Collapse 2</button>
      <div class="form-group" ng-show="show==1">
      <div class="sec">show 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="show==2">
      <div class="sec">show 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="show==3">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I see you notice bootstrap and only with angular. Can I suggest [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?

Comment: @Giovani Vercauteren not possible that, only angular ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2s6ojLqk/) that should meet the requirement you're looking for. There are a few changes, but it seems to be working.  It doesn't use bootstrap, but you need ng-animate for your animations.

I've put a wrapper around your form-group elements, and I've changed the `ng-show` to `ng-if`.

```
//html
<button ng-click="showDiv(1)" class="btn">collapse 1</button>
<button ng-click="showDiv(2)" class="btn">Collapse 2</button>

<div class="sec-wrp" ng-if="show === 1">
    <div class="form-group" >
      <div class="sec">show 1</div>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="sec-wrp" ng-if="show === 2">
    <div class="form-group" >
      <div class="sec">show 2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-if="show==3" >
</div>
```

The click event now calls a function in your controller with the value of the div you want to show. The controller responds by setting the `$scope.show` value to 0. If the `currentShow` value is zero (as it is intialized), it sets the `$scope.show` value to the value passed and resets the `currentShow` variable to the new value with no timeout.  If the value passed equals the `currentShow` value, it treats it as a toggle by not resetting `$scope.show` and resetting `currentShow` to zero, closing the div. If the int passed does not equal `currentShow`, it sets `currentShow` and `$scope.show` to the new value.

```
//controller
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('Test', ['$timeout','$scope', function($timeout, $scope) {
    $scope.show = 0;
    var currentShow = 0;

    $scope.showDiv = function(int){
        $scope.show = 0;

        if(currentShow === 0){
           currentShow = int;
           $scope.show = int;
           return false;
        }

        if(currentShow === int){
           $timeout(function(){
               currentShow = 0;
               return false;
           }, 1000)
        }else{
           $timeout(function(){
               currentShow = int;
               $scope.show = int;
           }, 1000)
        }
    }

}]);
```

The `$timeout` value of one second corresponds to the transition times of the animations, i.e., the allows a one second waiting time for the 1 second animation to complete in your css, which uses ng-enter, ng-leave instead of keyframes.  If you want to adjust the transition times here, just make sure you also adjust the $timeouts.

```
//css
.custom{position: relative; z-index: 2; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
.sec{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid orangered;
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sec-wrp{
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

.sec-wrp.ng-enter{
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.sec-wrp.ng-enter.ng-enter-active{
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

.sec-wrp.ng-leave{
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

.sec-wrp.ng-leave.ng-leave-active{
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to help :)